# Powershell: Checking a checkbox is not working. Debugging looks fine

Tags: powershell, checkbox

```
$GetLockoutStatus = Get-ADUser -Identity $WPFnamelookupbox.Text | Select-Object Enabled
    if($GetLockoutStatus -eq $true){
        $WPFlockedaccount.IsChecked = $true
    }
```

The issue I have is that the checkbox does not seem to be getting checked. I can run the powershell command manually just fine and it shows that the account is enabled but not happening visually with the checkbox.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Select` you have an object with just the `Enabled` property. You can either add that property to your `if` statement:

```
if($GetLockoutStatus.enabled -eq $true){
```

Or you can expand the property first:

```
$GetLockoutStatus = Get-ADUser -Identity $WPFnamelookupbox.Text | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled
```

Or you could get the property using `().Enabled`

```
$GetLockoutStatus = (Get-ADUser -Identity $WPFnamelookupbox.Text).Enabled
```